# Error when applying symbology layer to output raster

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, error-000732

I've created a symbology layer that I want to apply to my output raster. I tried the following code:

```
FINAL_RESULTS = os.path.join(config.RASTER_FINAL_RESULT_FOLDER,"ThresholdResults_Day_{0}.tif".format(yesterdaysJulianDate))
combineResults(intermediateResultRasters, FINAL_RESULTS)
print "Processing Finished"

# Add Symbology from template layer
Symbology_lyr = "C:\\Users\\uma.bhandaram\\Desktop\\Threshold\\thresholdcalculation\\resources\\    Symbology.lyr"
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(FINAL_RESULTS, Symbology_lyr)
print "Symbology Applied"
```

I run into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\Threshold\thresholdcalculation\thresholdCalculation\calculateYesterdaysThreshold.py", line 73, in <module>
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(FINAL_RESULTS, Symbology_lyr)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6438, in ApplySymbologyFromLayer
raise e
 ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.

 ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset  C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\Threshold\thresholdcalculation\thresholdCalculation\..\resources\output\results\ThresholdResults_Day_31.tif does not exist or is not supported
 Failed to execute (ApplySymbologyFromLayer).
```

The output raster is created and exists so I'm not sure why the error says otherwise?

Here's the full code:
    import datetime
    import arcpy, config
    import os, ntpath, sys
    from arcpy.sa import *

```
if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
    arcpy.AddMessage("Checking out Spatial")
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
else:
    arcpy.AddError("Unable to get spatial analyst extension")
    sys.exit(0)


def dateToJulianDay(date):
    """Returns the Julian day number of a date."""
    return date.timetuple().tm_yday


def getFiles(day):
     DAY_MIN_RASTER = 'Obs_Min_2017_{0}.tif'.format(day)
     DAY_MAX_RASTER = 'Obs_Max_2017_{0}.tif'.format(day)
    return os.path.join(config.INPUT_DAILY_RASTER_MAX_LOC, DAY_MAX_RASTER), \
       os.path.join(config.INPUT_DAILY_RASTER_MIN_LOC, DAY_MIN_RASTER)


def createRasterBasedOnValue(raster, trueValue, falseValue, conditional,    outputLocation, ):
    conRaster = Con(raster, trueValue, falseValue, conditional)
    conRaster.save(outputLocation)


def combineResults(rasterList, output):
    outCellStats = CellStatistics(rasterList, "SUM", "DATA")
    outCellStats.save(output) 


yesterdaysJulianDate = dateToJulianDay(datetime.datetime.today()) - 1
print "Process started for day {0}".format(yesterdaysJulianDate)

maxRastFile, minRastFile = getFiles(str(yesterdaysJulianDate).zfill(3))
MinRaster = Raster(minRastFile)
MaxRaster = Raster(maxRastFile)

intermediateResultRasters = []
TO_APPEND_TO_RESULT = yesterdaysJulianDate

RESULT_X32 = os.path.join(config.RASTER_INTERMEDIATE_RESULT_OUTPUT_FOLDER,
                         "ConLess32_{0}.tif".format(ntpath.basename(minRastFile)))

createRasterBasedOnValue(MinRaster, 0, 5, "\"VALUE\" < 32", RESULT_X32)
intermediateResultRasters.append(RESULT_X32)

RESULT_X45 = os.path.join(config.RASTER_INTERMEDIATE_RESULT_OUTPUT_FOLDER,
                      "ConLess45_{0}".format(ntpath.basename(minRastFile)))
createRasterBasedOnValue(MaxRaster, 10, 15, "\"VALUE\" < 45",RESULT_X45)
intermediateResultRasters.append(RESULT_X45)

RESULT_X85 = os.path.join(config.RASTER_INTERMEDIATE_RESULT_OUTPUT_FOLDER,
                      "ConLess85_{0}".format(ntpath.basename(maxRastFile)))
createRasterBasedOnValue(MaxRaster, 20, 25, "\"VALUE\" < 85", RESULT_X85)
intermediateResultRasters.append(RESULT_X85)

RESULT_X95 = os.path.join(config.RASTER_INTERMEDIATE_RESULT_OUTPUT_FOLDER,
                      "ConLess95_{0}".format(ntpath.basename(maxRastFile)))
createRasterBasedOnValue(MaxRaster, 30, 0, "\"VALUE\" < 95", RESULT_X95)
intermediateResultRasters.append(RESULT_X95)
FINAL_RESULTS = os.path.join(config.RASTER_FINAL_RESULT_FOLDER,
                           "ThresholdResults_Day_{0}.tif".format(yesterdaysJulianDate))
combineResults(intermediateResultRasters, FINAL_RESULTS)
print "Processing Finished"

# Add Symbology from template layer
Symbology_lyr = "C:\\Users\\uma.bhandaram\\Desktop\\Threshold\\thresholdcalculation\\resources\\ Symbology.lyr"
 arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(FINAL_RESULTS, Symbology_lyr)
 print "Symbology Applied"
```

Comment: What happens when you run the precise [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that you have presented?  i.e. what is the error message including line number from that rather than the one from running your whole code?